# Set gapless loop single audio playback in just_audio package for flutter app

Tags: flutter, loops, audio, just-audio, playsound

I am new in flutter and trying to build a music player app which will play short sound clips like white noise, pink noise, jack hammer etc. This app requires to play a single sound continuously and uninterruptedly. My idea was to use `just_audio` feature `setLoopMode` method in looping sound. I tried this..

```
final player = AudioPlayer(); // Create a player
await player.setAsset('audio/nature.mp3');
player.play();
await player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
```

It works but between stop and play there is a gap while repeating that sound. Also trying `LoopMode.all` does the same. No luck to get rid of that gap while playing a single sound.

**Update**

```
final playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
   // Start loading next item just before reaching it
   useLazyPreparation: true,
  // Specify the playlist items
  children: [
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track1.mp3')),
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track1.mp3')),
    AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('https://example.com/track1.mp3')),
  ],
);
await player.setAudioSource(playlist, initialIndex: 0, initialPosition: Duration.zero);
player.play();
```

I did a trick here using same audio file to play the song. It is playing sounds gapless. But No idea if it is a proper way to accomplish the task.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the loop with this,

```
player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.all);
```

Comment: I tried that also, same as before.